# Orders of Abelianzation of groups

Tags: group-theory

I started to read the section "finite or infinite" of the book "presentation of groups" by Johnson.
I scanned my question in the following picture:

[image]

I could not find any clue in this book regarding the computation the order of Abelianzation of a given group $G$.
I was wondering if somebody tells me how can I use  $det$ for the size of $G/G'$.

But I do not have any idea concerning the following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}5 & -3  \\ 
3 & -2  \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: The matrix you have computed is not in Smith Normal Form. In a matrix in SNF, all of the entries not on the main diagonal must be 0, and each element of the diagonal must divide the next one down i.e. $A_{ii}$ divides $A_{i+1,i+1}$ for all $i$). The correct Smith Normal Form of $G/G'$ would  tell you its abelianization immediately.

Comment: @DerekHolt, OK my question is How could he conclude that $[G:G']=\begin{pmatrix}5 & -3  \\ 
3 & -2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$?